# COM порт номером выше 19-и и Visual Basic

Tags: windows, visual-basic, порт

Такой вопрос. Моё устройство (преобразователь usb - com) в виндоуз получило номер com21. А Visual Basic отказывается работать с номерами старше 19. Как быть?

Comment: спасибо. через диспетчер устройств получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Переназначить через диспетчер устройств номер COM-порта.